# How to click button when navigating website?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to open a website, login, select report, and save in Excel format.

I managed to open IE, navigate to the site, enter Username/Password and login.

How do I select the webpage button to open the report page?

Below is the portion of the button on the website I'm attempting to click and code I've tried, both do not give any error message they simply don't do anything.

Website HTML
[image]

```vb
Sub vbamacro()
    
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim IEPage As Object
    Dim IEPageElement As Object
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    
    'Enter website name below
    
    IE.Navigate "websitename"
    
    'Ready state means wait until the website has loaded
    
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set IEPage = IE.Document
    
    Set IEPageElement = IEPage.getElementById("ctl00__contentPlaceHolder__txtUserID")
    IEPageElement.Value = "username"
    
    Set IEPageElement = IEPage.getElementById("ctl00__contentPlaceHolder__txtPassword")
    IEPageElement.Value = "password"
    
    Set IEPageElement = IEPage.getElementById("ctl00__contentPlaceHolder__btnLogin")
    IEPageElement.Click
    
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    With IE.Document
    
        Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("Li")
        For Each e In elems
    
            If (e.getAttribute("ID") = "Reports3") Then
                e.Click
                Exit For
            End If
    
        Next e
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Also tried;

```vb
For each e in ie.document.getElementsByTagName("Li") 
    If e.ID = "Reports3" Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating directly to the href of the desired element

```
IE.navigate(e.href)
```

Also you are clicking “Li” tag element, you have to get the Li children’s  tag witch is “a” (the one that has the href property)

Comment: Thanks that worked! Seems like i was making it more complicated then it needed to be